How to handle alerts in nodriver?
I am transitioning my work from using an undetectable Chrome driver to using the nodriver library (https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/nodriver). I need help handling alerts, as I couldn't find relevant information in the API documentation.
Here is a specific example of what I want to achieve:

Click a button.
Wait for an alert to appear within a specified time (e.g., 10 seconds).
If an alert appears within the specified time:

Print the alert text.
Accept the alert.


If no alert appears within the specified time, do nothing.

Could you provide guidance or a code example on how to accomplish this using nodriver?

maybe this module doesn't have function which you try to find in documentation. You may have to ask author of this module.

Test code below:
import nodriver as uc
import asyncio

class NodriverAlert(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = None
        self.alert_message = None

    async def js_alert_message(self, event: uc.cdp.page):
        if 'JavascriptDialogOpening' in str(type(event)):
            # print(f'Alert class return: {event}')
            self.alert_message = event.message
            print(f'The alert message is: {self.alert_message}')
        
        elif 'JavascriptDialogClosed' in str(type(event)):
            print(event)
            print('Close alert')
            event.result = True
        
        else: 
            print(event)

    async def js_alert_message_click(self, event: uc.cdp.page):
        if self.alert_message != None:
            try:
                response = await asyncio.wait_for(self.tab.send(uc.cdp.page.handle_java_script_dialog(accept=False)), timeout=10.0)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                response = 'timeout'
            print(f'Alert OK! - response: {response}')
        else:
            print('sem alert')

        
    async def main(self):
        url = 'https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/alerts/alert-test.html'
        self.browser = await uc.start()
        self.tab = await self.browser.get(url)

        # We'll need to add a handler
        self.tab.add_handler(uc.cdp.page, self.js_alert_message)
        self.tab.add_handler(uc.cdp.page, self.js_alert_message_click)

        # Now, display an alert
        print('Click to show alert...')
        show_alert_box_btn = await self.tab.find('#alertexamples')
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(show_alert_box_btn.mouse_click(), timeout=5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
        print('Finish!')


example = NodriverAlert()
asyncio.run(example.main())

print(example.alert_message)


